Animated movie about mice
I remember a movie from childhood and I wanted to look it up, but I've forgotten most of the details!
Here's what I remember:

It's animated
It's about mice
I think the mice are Italian?
The mice are immigrating to America in search of a better life


Is it Ratatoulie , where rat becomes cook ??

Sounds like you're talking about An American Tail.
The mice in the film are Russian, not Italian, but it's otherwise the same story.

An American Tail is a 1986 American animated musical adventure film directed by Don Bluth and produced by Sullivan Bluth Studios and Amblin Entertainment. The film tells the story of Fievel Mousekewitz and his family as they immigrate from Russia to the United States for freedom. However, Fievel gets lost and must find a way to reunite with his family. 

Here's the trailer for the film:



